# How to assign one char* to another char*

Tags: c++

Its my first question here.

I have a piece of code:

```
char* str1 = "yes" ;
char* str2 = "no" ;
*str1 = *str2;    //----crash

*str1 = *str2; //here program crashes.
```

When I can do the same with integer pointers, then why not with char pointers.
Please explain.

Comment: The reason is you don't have access to the memory where `"yes"` is actually stored.

Comment: The expression value of `"yes"` is not a `char*` its a `const char*`. But for some inexplicable reason it was decided to allow programmers to set `char*` to a *const* area of memory even though it never makes sense.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand from your question. Do you want to make str1 the same string as str or do you want to change the first character of str1 to the first character of str2?

Comment: @BanachTarski I want to assign the value of str2 to str1.

Comment: So use `str2 = str1` - but if you want to COPY `str2` to `str1`, then you need to a) have space to store a copy (NOT a pointer to another constant string), b) use `strcpy` or write code yourself to store it.

Comment: Either assign pointers using str1 = str2 (if the strings remain the same) or use strcpy (you must allocate space first) or use stl::string (easiest). I'd go for the latter, unless this is an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that `char*` is a pointer to a `char`, not a string object. A literal `"yes"` is actually a `const char*`, because the literals will be constant data in the programms data section. For compatibility with C C++ still allows to initialize a `char`* with a `const char*`.

Also note, that the unary `*` operator on a pointer dereferences the pointer.

Now that you do here is assigning the first character of `str2` (`'n'`) to the first character of `str1`. Since the first character of `str1` is a constant in the programs data section, that will of course fail.

If you really want to assign the first `char`, first produce a `char` array on the heap:

```
char* str1 = (char*)malloc(4); // here str1 is non const
strncpy(str1, "yes", 4);

const char* str2 = "no";

*str1 = *str2; // now str1 contains "nes".
```

I assume you are trying to work with strings. Please prefer `std::string`:

```
std::string str1 = std::string("yes");
std::string str2 = std::string("no");

str1 = str2 // now str1 is "no" as well.
```

With C++14 string literals you can make it even more elegant:

```
auto str1 = "yes"s;
auto str2 = "no"s;

str1 = str2 // now str1 is "no" as well.
```

Whenever reasonable, use the standard library instead of C legacy constructs. You probably won't get it better.

Comment: Re “A literal `"yes"` is actually a `const char*`”, no, it's not. It's an array of 4 `char const`, i.e. `char const[4]`. In expressions where a pointer is expected an expression denoting this array decays to a pointer to first item, so you can use it as initializer for, or assign it to, a `char const*` object.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you are correct, but I think, going so much into detail would have made my answer ununderstandable for C++ beginners. The core issue is, that the OPs code breaks const-correctness. I think, that is better understandable with my simplification.

Answer (score 4):

This original code,

```
char* str1 = "yes" ;
char* str2 = "no" ;
*str1 = *str2;    //----crash

*str1 = *str2; //here program crashes.
```

… is **invalid**, not permitted, as of C++11 and later. We're now at C++14 and in a short while will presumably be at C++17.

What does a C++11 compiler say about it? E.g., what does MinGW g++ 5.1.0 with option `-std=c++14`, say about it?

```
C:\my\forums\so\121> g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:3:18: error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
     char* str1 = "yes" ;
                  ^
foo.cpp:4:18: error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
     char* str2 = "no" ;
                  ^

C:\my\forums\so\121> _
```

However, Visual C++ 2015 update 2 erroneously accepts the code.

The reason why the implicit conversion to `char*` was dropped from the language was precisely that it's unsafe. It allows the code to attempt modification of the literals, as this code does. But the literals can be stored in read-only memory, which then can cause a crash (as it did for the OP), or other undesirable behavior. It's just **Undefined Behavior**, where anything can happen, including that the code appears to “work”.

---

How to fix it?

Use **`std::string`**.

Like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    string str1 = "yes" ;
    string str2 = "no" ;
    str1 = str2;    // OK.
}
```

---

If you absolutely want to use C level zero-terminated strings handled via pointers, perhaps in order to be compatible with some C code, then use `const` as appropriate for pointers, use local or dynamically allocated arrays for storage as appropriate, and use the C standard library's string functions, or roll your own, they're very simple functions:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>     // The ".h" header is a C++ version of C's header.

auto main() -> int
{
    char str1[] = "yes" ;
    char const* const str2 = "no" ;

    int const n2 = strlen( str2 );
    assert( sizeof( str1 ) > n2 );
    strcpy( str1, str2 );
    assert( strcmp( str1, "no" ) == 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the OP simply wants to make `str1` to `"no"`

Instead of

```
*str1 = *str2;
```

You should do

```
str1 = str2;
```

`str1` is a pointer that points to the first character of the given string.
`*str` dereferences the pointer giving you the first character of the string `str1`. So what your code was doing was trying to make the first character of `str1` to the first character of `str2`

In my code, I am making `str1` point to the same location ass `str2` which in effect will give you two variables pointing to the same memory location.

If you want to copy the contents of str2 to str1 then use the `strcpy` function.